# How to display an array as a ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm trying to display the contents of an array in a ListView on Android. I initially had the error

> ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

so I changed the ArrayAdapter from
`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.activity_list_item, weatherData);`

to

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.activity_list_item, R.id.list_item, weatherData);`

However I now get the error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find view with ID com.example.weatherapp:id/list_item in item layout

I was hoping that someone could help me fix this. The whole code is below

Java File

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        displayListView();

    }


    public void displayListView () {
        String[] weatherData = {"Today - Storm 8 / 12", "Tomorrow - Foggy 9 / 13", "Thurs - Rainy 8 / 13", "Fri - foggy 8 / 12", "Sat - Sunny 9 / 14", "Sun - Sunny 10 / 15", "Mon - Sunny 11 / 15" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.activity_list_item, R.id.list_item, weatherData);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void toastFunction (View view) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Refreshing Weather!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Welcome to weather dummy app :-)" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:onClick="toastFunction"
        android:text="Refresh" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/enterLocationName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Location Name" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</TextView>
```

Comment: you are not using `listitem.xml`. what's inside `activity_list_item.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout name is listitem.xml and you are using list_item in adapter change this to R.id.listitem.